# Why does my code, reading a CSV file, print a dictionary, and not a list?

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

```
import unicodecsv

def read_csv(filename):
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        reader = unicodecsv.DictReader(f)
        return list(reader)

enrollments = read_csv('enrollments.csv')
daily_engagement = read_csv('daily-engagement.csv')
project_submissions = read_csv('project-submissions.csv')
```

In the previous lesson I was learning how to read a CSV file and convert it to an editable format. The code works great but when I was trying to understand the code, and I don't understand why, when I print `enrollments[0]`, that the result is a dictionary.

The first part of the function uses `with open(filename, 'rb') as f:` I understand that it is used to open the file.

The next part is `reader = unicodecsv.DictReader(f)`, I understand that it is used for mapping the information read, into a dictionary.

The third part is where I'm having difficulties understanding, the `return list(reader)` line. Doesn't this line mean that the `reader` variable is returned as a `list()`?

So why it is returning a dictionary when I use print?

```
print enrollments[0]

{u'account_key': u'448',
 u'cancel_date': u'2015-01-14',
 u'days_to_cancel': u'65',
 u'is_canceled': u'True',
 u'is_udacity': u'True',
 u'join_date': u'2014-11-10',
 u'status': u'canceled'}
```

Comment: its a list of dictionaries! what was the expected output?

Comment: "``the second part reader = unicodecsv.DictReader(f) I understand that it is used for maping the information read into a dict.``" that's not what it does. it's a class instance of ``DictReader``, not a ``dict``.

Comment: try return list(list(reader) not sure if this is what you want...

Comment: What output did you expect? You actually have a list of dictionaries.

Comment: @MikeScotty: no, **they have it *almost* right**. `DictReader()` takes rows from the file, and produces dictionaries *for each row*. Sure, `DictReader()` **itself** is a `DictReader()` instance, but it's responsibility is still to map the information read from the file to dictionaries.

Comment: @Rinogg: that's not even valid Python. `list(list(reader))` would create a new list with all the same elements as `list(reader)`, which is *not helpful here*. You probably meant `[list(reader)]`, which is a new list with one element, another list. That won't help the OP understand what is happening however. Please, when people are learning to program, *try to only answer if you are yourself proficient in the language*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the second part `reader = unicodecsv.DictReader(f)` I understand that it is used for maping the information read into a dict.

You are *close*, but not quite correct.

`DictReader()` puts **each row** in the input CSV file into a dictionary. So you get a *series* of dictionaries, no a single dictionary. You got those rows by *iterating*, like using a `for` loop (`for row in reader: ...`). `list()` uses `reader` as an iterator to create a list of all the rows.

> `return list(reader)` In here ain't I telling the computer to return the variable reader as a list?

Yes, you are passing the `reader` object to `list()`, which produces a list object from *all the rows in the file*. Each row is converted to a dictionary, so the end result is a *list of dictionaries*. You could see this as `result = []` `for row in reader: result.append(row)`, and the `result` list is what is returned from the function.

You then take that list, and *index* the list with `0`, so you ask for the *first* entry in the list:

```
print enrollments[0]
```

This doesn't print the whole list, this prints **one element *from* the list**. And that one element is a dictionary because that's the data for the first row of data in the file.

If you wanted to print the list itself, use

```
print enrollment
```

Answer (score 0):

enrollments is a list

enrollments[0] is a dict

So enrollments is a list of dictionaries.

Everything worked as expected, read_csv returns a list (of dictionaties)